# ConnectionError using Requests (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests, connection

I am trying to get data from this webpage using the requests module, but keep encountering connection issues. I have tried a few suggestions from stack overflow, but none seems to be effective so far.

It throws a number of issues including:

1. Max retries exceeded with url: /Click2GovTX/accountsinfo.html?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=DMRH-B8MI-ZBRR-S7VN-830D-O8QC-RB9S-54CK&accountsByAddressView=true&paging.pagingId=T422181946&paging.lastRecord=0107&paging.pageNumber=2
2. NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/importtesting.py', wdir='C:/Users/wdir')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-97dea6983eaf>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/importtesting.py', wdir='C:/Users/wdir)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/importtesting.py", line 41, in <module>
    pagedata = session.get(website,verify=False)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='egov2.manchesternh.gov', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /Click2GovTX/accountsinfo.html?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=DMRH-B8MI-ZBRR-S7VN-830D-O8QC-RB9S-54CK&accountsByAddressView=true&paging.pagingId=T422181946&paging.lastRecord=0107&paging.pageNumber=2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001ABCF3A2088>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

The code is below:

```
import requests
import urllib #did try to use urllib, but didn't work
from urllib.request import urlopen

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry


website='http://egov2.manchesternh.gov/Click2GovTX/accountsinfo.html?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=DMRH-B8MI-ZBRR-S7VN-830D-O8QC-RB9S-54CK&accountsByAddressView=true&paging.pagingId=T422181946&paging.lastRecord=0107&paging.pageNumber=2'

session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

pagedata = session.get(website,verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not a problem with your Python code (unless you got the URL wrong). This looks like a problem with the web server you are trying to connect to. Use something *other* than your code to verify, eg. a web browser or a command-line tool like curl.

Here's what I get when I try to access that web server with curl:

```
$ curl http://egov2.manchesternh.gov/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to egov2.manchesternh.gov port 80: Connection refused
```

So, either you have the wrong URL, or somebody's web server is down. Not a problem with your code.